# Global timer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, video, timer, long-polling

A new page is created on my website, website.com/NewPage
I want the video on this page to start in 20 seconds of the page being created.

At the moment, I have a `setTimeout` function that waits 20 seconds then starts the video. The problem with that is the 20 second timer starts when EACH USER connects. My goal is to have the website **start the video 20 seconds after the page is created**, for **everyone**. Here is an example:

*User A* enters website.com/NewPage within 3 seconds of the page being created.
*User B* enters website.com/NewPage within 15 seconds of the page being created.

5 seconds after *User B* connects, *User A*'s video starts.
*User B* is at 5 seconds and has to wait 15 seconds for the video to start.

My goal is to get it so that the video starts for everyone at the exact same time, as long as they joined before 20 seconds (Nobody else can join after 20 seconds).

So even if *User B* joined late, It will start at the exact same time for everyone.

Comment: What do you mean by "page is created"? How can your timeout affect multiple users, isn't it located on the client side? If no, how does your server trigger the video starts?

Answer (score 1):

It has to be coordinated on the server.  You tagged this with long-polling, so I suppose that's the server communications technique you are using.  When the first long-polling connection is opened for a new page, then start a timer on the server.

Comment: well, what is the backend server stack?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sharing a timer among different users, I think you need to maintain the timer in the backend. And in the front-end JavaScript, maintain a separate timer for each user (on their local browser).

Say, your front-end code maybe:

```
var timer = null;
document.onload = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/server/timer',
        type: 'get',
        data: {userName: 'user A'}
    }).done(function (res) {
        if (res.remaining && res.remaining >= 0) {
            alert('Hi, please wait for ' + res.remaining + ' seconds to start playing video');
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                 // play the video
            }, res.remaining * 1000);
        } else {
            alert('Sorry, you cannot watch the video now');
        }
    });
}
```

In your backend code, maintain the API `/server/timer` to make sure the countdown is the same for every user.

Comment: Is their any way to do it without using ajax? I feel like their should be a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: @AjaxjQuery I think no other way. Image you have 10 users, they visit your site in every 2 seconds. Then for each of them, you need to have some mechanism to inform him: 'Hey man, your video starts in 9 seconds.' How do you know the number is `9`? You need to maintain the number somehow.